# How does Big Query store millions of rows of a column with categorical (duplicate) string values?

Tags: optimization, google-bigquery, query-optimization, storage

We are streaming around a million records per day into BQ and a particular string column has categorical values of "High", "Medium" and "Low".

I am trying to understand if Biq Query does storage optimisations other than compression at its own end and what is the scale of that? Looked for documentation on this and was unable to find explanations on the same.

For example if i have:

```
**Col1**
High
High
Medium
Low
High
Low
**... 100 Million Rows**
```

Would BQ Store it internally as follows

```
**Col1**
1
1
2
3
1
3
**... 100 Million Rows**
```

Comment: Would appreciate feedback on the question in case you are down voting, thank you.

Comment: The downvote wasn't me, but did you see the [blog post on Capacitor](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/04/inside-capacitor-bigquerys-next-generation-columnar-storage-format)?

Comment: I think, it is important to note: no matter how data is compressed, stored - users are still billed based on original data size (not compressed)!

Answer (score 2):

Summary of noteworthy (and correct!) answers:

- As Elliott pointed out in the comments, you can read details on BigQuery's data compression [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/04/inside-capacitor-bigquerys-next-generation-columnar-storage-format).
- As Felipe notes, there is no need to consider these details as a user of BigQuery. All such optimizations are done behind the scenes, and are being improved continuously as BigQuery evolves without any action on your part.
- As Mikhail notes in the comments, you are billed by the logical data size, regardless of any optimizations applied at the storage layer.

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery constantly improves the underlying storage - and this all happens without any user interaction.

To see the original ideas behind BigQuery's columnar storage, read the Dremel paper:

- https://ai.google/research/pubs/pub36632

To see the most recent published improvements in storage, see Capacitor:

- https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/04/inside-capacitor-bigquerys-next-generation-columnar-storage-format

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery relies on Colossus, Google’s latest generation distributed file system. Each Google datacenter has its own Colossus cluster, and each Colossus cluster has enough disks to give every BigQuery user thousands of dedicated disks at a time. 
You may gather more detail from the "BigQuery under the hood" [page](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/01/bigquery-under-the-hood).